# Redis store data in backup.db file

Tags: docker, redis

I have RedisDB that exists in a Docker container. Database restored from dump.rdb file and everything works well (I can get all data that stored in Redis before) until Redis tries to save data in the background. Log here:

```
1:M 28 Jan 2021 11:28:28.035 * 100 changes in 300 seconds. Saving...
1:M 28 Jan 2021 11:28:28.349 * Background saving started by pid 21
21:C 28 Jan 2021 11:30:23.589 * DB saved on disk
21:C 28 Jan 2021 11:30:23.930 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
```

And after that, I see in the folder a new file: **backup.db**, and all data I get from this file (instead of dump.rdb).

**redis.conf**:

```
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir ./
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

**Docker run command**:

```
docker run --name redis -p 6379:6379 -v /redis/data:/data -v /redis/config/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf -d redis
```

**dump.rdb** file stored into */redis/data* folder and **redis.conf** stored into */redis/config* folder

Redis version: 6.0.10

Question: How to avoid creation backup.db file?

Comment: What is your question here? It is not clear

Comment: @Malathi, fixed